# bash one-liner: set variable to output of command or to default value if output is empty

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

I know that in Bash you can use the syntax

```
editor=${new_editor:-/usr/bin/vi}
```

which will set `editor` to `new_editor` if the variable `new_editor` is not empty and to `/usr/bin/vi` otherwise. Is it possible to produce similar one-liner, which will set `editor` to output of some command and to some default value if the output is empty? Something like (only as example, this does not work)

```
editor=$( $(which emacs) :-/usr/bin/vi )
```

I know how to do it in several lines of code, but would like to know if an elegant solution exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

POSIXLY:

```
$ : "${editor:=$(command -v emacs)}" "${editor:=/usr/bin/vi}"
$ printf '%s\n' "$editor"
emacs
```

---

You can't do nested parameter expansion in any Bourne-like shells but `zsh`:

```
$ editor=${$(whence -p emacs):-/usr/bin/vi}
$ print -rl -- $editor
/usr/bin/emacs
```

or:

```
editor=${commands[emacs]-$commands[vi]}
```

Comment: For the first one, ITYM `: "${editor:=$(command -v emacs)}" "${editor:=/usr/bin/vi}"` (assuming `$editor` was previously empty/unset)

Comment: In `zsh`, see also `editor=${commands[emacs]-$commands[vi]}`